# application load and content testing

Tags: testing, vaadin, load-testing

I'm looking for some tool which can be easily used (I have to learn how it works and use it in 1-2 days) and which can simulate users entering web application with types:
- person who slowly watching content of web page
- user "jumping" from one directory to another without even reading content
- user checking product after product available on site
- someone trying to enter admin content 
- person who tries to enter inaccessible parts of application
- person who tries to enter content which does not exist

very important is to be able to check is what user see is what he should see (like error messages, "you don't have permission to enter", how which elements of page user see, how many products on main page he see etc.)

Which tool will be best for that? I use Vaadin, is there anything for this technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that learning how to use and deploy a new testing tool in 1-2 days is extraordinarily optimistic! I don't believe you will be able to deploy *any* testing tool against anything other than an exceptionally simple application in that timescale.

That said:

We've used [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (Apache 2 License) to perform some load-testing on our Vaadin application; see [this article](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JMeter%20Testing) for more details on how to start using JMeter & Vaadin.

We use  [QFTest](http://qfs.de) (Commercial License) to perform functional testing on our Vaadin application.

You can also use [Vaadin's TestBench](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/testbench) (Commercial License)  to perform functional testing - and I imagine you could probably perform some kind of low-level loadtesting with it. Testbench is built on top of [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) (Apache 2 License) - with specific hooks and extensions specifically for Vaadin applications. Those hooks are pretty important, and you'll probably end up having to re-implement them yourself.

We use QFTest as we have significant experience using it, and also use it to test our Swing applications too. It provides a pretty sophisticated UI to enable you to build your tests without having to write much code (although, ultimately, you *are* writing code) - this provides productivity to some QA Analysts who don't like thinking in code.

All of these tools will realistically require you to assign HTML ID's to components in your application <sup>1</sup> to make it easy to develop tests for it; without id's or some other form of identifier - we've used CSS classes too - it becomes hard to make a test repeatable.
[1]

---

<sup>1</sup> Using Vaadin 6's [Paintable#setDebugId](https://vaadin.com/api/6.8.9/com/vaadin/terminal/Paintable.html#setDebugId%28java.lang.String%29)  or Vaadin 7's [Component#setId](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.3/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29)